# java.sql.SQLException: Login failed for user 'sa'

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I am having trouble connecting to my SQL Server database through a jtds connection:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/MnA;instance=SQLEXPRESS", "sa","");
```

SQL Server is enabled, TCP/IP is enabled, Mixed server authentication is enabled

Any ideas?

[image: SQL Server is running]

[image: TCP/IP is enabled]

[image]

[image]

java.sql.SQLException: Login failed for user 'sa'.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:368)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2820)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2258)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.login(TdsCore.java:603)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.(ConnectionJDBC2.java:345)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC3.(ConnectionJDBC3.java:50)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at DB.dbConnect(testConnection.java:17)
    at testConnection.main(testConnection.java:7)

Comment: Do you have a full stacktrace?

Comment: This is off topic for SO; belongs on [dba.se]

Comment: What happens when you try to log in using those credentials in SSMS?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your jdts jar version is 1.2x. If it is not ,download correct version. And the second option is using JDBC jar for connecting MSSQL database.

Answer (score 0):

You are logging in with SQL Authentication, passing in SA as the login and (blank) as the password.  Do you know the actual password for SA?  If it is truly blank, I strongly suggest you change it to something else and try that in your connection string.

I also suggest you use a login other that SA, unless you truly want your users to have the ability to drop databases, add users, and perform other adminstrator level tasks.